# How to rename columns by their number?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got some dataset that is updated once in a while. I want to make an automatic analysis of that dataset, so I've made an R script. The problem is, that with every update the names of the columns change but their order stays the same. I want to rename the colums no matter what name it got this time. I wanted to use `rename()` from dplyr, but it requires the old **names** of the columns. I tried something like that:

```
dataset %<>% rename('new.name1'=.[[1]], 'new.name2'=.[[2]], 'new.name3'=.[[3]])
```

but it didn't work. So how can I replace the old name with column number in the `rename()` function? Or what other function can I use to get it done?

Comment: You can use `set_names()`, just make sure you have the correct order...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full example to my comment:

```r
dataset <- ...
new_names <- c("new_name_1", "new_name_2", ...)
dataset <- dataset %>% set_names(new_names)
```

If you only want to replace some older names, use something like this:

```r
dataset <- ...
mtch <- c("old_name_2" = "new_name_2", ...)
new_names <- names(dataset)
new_names[names(mtch)] <- as.character(mtch)
dataset <- dataset %>% set_names(new_names)
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late to be of use to the OP. But for new readers stumbling here, you can use `rename()` in the usual way even with the column numbers as the old name. Just drop the `.[[i]]`'s and use the column number by itself:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
iris %>%
    rename("NEW_NAME" = 1) %>%
    head
#>   NEW_NAME Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1      5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2      4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3      4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4      4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5      5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6      5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As with @David's 2nd solution, this solution lets you rename only specific columns, though in a bit more straightforward way IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setNames` :

```
dataset <- setNames(dataset, paste0('new.name', seq_along(dataset)))
```